# Directx C++ - Drawing DNA Shape

Tags: c++, algorithm, winapi, math, directx

In my current program I would like to be able to draw "DNA Shapes". I have written a "DrawPixel(x,y,r,g,b)" function which can draw a pixel on the screen. Moving on from this point I implemented the [Bresenham line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) to draw a line as: "DrawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2,r,g,b)".

Now I realized that using an image for the DNA shapes would be a very bad choice (in multiple aspects). So I tried making a function to draw a DNA shape (As I couldn't find an algorithm). This is currently based on a circle drawing algorithm ([Midpoint Circle Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm)):

```
void D3DGHandler::DrawDNAShape(int x1, int y1, int length, int curves, int dir 
                               int off, int r, int g, int b){
     int x2Pos = sin(dir)*length+x1;
     int y2Pos = cos(dir)*length+y1;


     for (int i = 0; i < curves; i++) {
          int xIncrease = (x2Pos / curves) * i;
          int yIncrease = (y2Pos / curves) * i;

          int rSquared = off * off;
          int xPivot = (int)(off * 0.707107 + 0.5f);
          for (int x = 0; x <= xPivot; x++) {
               int y = (int)(sqrt((float)(rSquared - x*x)) + 0.5f);
               DrawPixel(x1+x+xIncrease,y1+y+yIncrease,r,g,b);
               DrawPixel(x1-x+xIncrease,y1+y+yIncrease,r,g,b);
               DrawPixel(x1+x+xIncrease,y1-y+yIncrease,r,g,b);
               DrawPixel(x1-x+xIncrease,y1-y+yIncrease,r,g,b);
               DrawPixel(x1+y+xIncrease,y1+x+yIncrease,r,g,b);
               DrawPixel(x1-y+xIncrease,y1+x+yIncrease,r,g,b);
               DrawPixel(x1+y+xIncrease,y1-x+yIncrease,r,g,b);
               DrawPixel(x1-y+xIncrease,y1-x+yIncrease,r,g,b);
          }
     }
}
```

This implementation is currently getting me some completely new functionality I was not looking for.

Along the lines of:

[image: DrawDNAShape()]

I would be very happy to hear any information you can give me!

**Update**

Expected result:

[Expected Result](http://www.radiostadharlingen.nl/programmas/dna-van-50-jaar-popmuziek/image)

But then way more line-like.

Comment: Can you give an example image of what you want to draw? DNA's double helix is a 3D shape so there are many ways to draw in in 2D.

Comment: @DavidBrown Sorry updated now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw two sinusoidal graphs with some offset will give you the required shape.

Eg. In R

```
x=(1:100)/10.0
plot(sin(x),x)
points(sin(x+2.5),x)
```

Comment: But if the offset was a bit high wouldn't drawing sin for example (as for x) mean that there would be gaps because there can be multiple pixels on each x?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.There are two strands, so there are two sets of sine plots. See: http://www.slideshare.net/dvidby0/the-dna-double-helix